# change point size of centroid for plot.betadisper

Tags: r, plot, centroid

I am trying to plot the groups and distances to centroids for a betadisper object.
I can control many of the characteristics, including the presence of a group label, segment colour, hull. I also understand how to change the point sizes for each sample, but I have not found a way to increase the size of the centroid point for each 'star'

```
data(varespec)

dis <- vegdist(varespec)

groups <- factor(c(rep(1,16), rep(2,8)), labels = c("grazed","ungrazed"))

mod <- betadisper(dis, groups)

plot(mod, label= FALSE , cex = 0.7)
```

What is the correct code to control the centroid size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the point size for the centroids is hard-wired in the code (`cex=1`) but a good work around is to just plot those points again with a bigger font.

```
## After your plot statement
points(mod$centroids[,1:2], pch=20, cex=2, col=1:2)
```

[image: Bigger centroids]